# ListView Checked Checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-sqlite, listviewitem

I am creating an Android application for communication learning

I make a List of word, it is contains a CheckBoxes and TextView, TextView is to display the the word, the use of the CheckBox is to determine what item in the ListView that I selected.

I store the id of the word in SQLite with "submit" button. when i close and open the activity again i want to see the checked checkboxes but this code only save to my database but not show the selected item when i open the activity again

this is the **Activity**

```
public class PerkembanganLevel1 extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ContentDao contentDao;
    private ChildDao childDao;
    private Child anakYangDipilih;

    public Global global;

    private AssessmentDao assessmentDao;
    private Assessment assessment;

    String idYangSudahBisa;

    PerkembanganAdapter perkembanganAdapter = null;

    ContentHistory contentHistory;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perkembangan_level1);

        contentDao = new ContentDao(this);
        contentDao.open();

        childDao = new ChildDao(this);
        childDao.open();

        anakYangDipilih = ((Global) getApplicationContext()).getChild();

        idYangSudahBisa = anakYangDipilih.getLevel1();

        ArrayList<ContentHistory> listKataLevel1 = (ArrayList<ContentHistory>) contentDao.getAllWordByLevel(1);

        perkembanganAdapter = new PerkembanganAdapter(this, R.layout.list_perkembangan, listKataLevel1);

        ListView level1 =  findViewById(R.id.LVPlv1);
        level1.setAdapter(perkembanganAdapter);
        Log.i("listKataLevel1 ", String.valueOf(listKataLevel1));
        level1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                contentHistory = (ContentHistory) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.BtnPLv1Submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                idYangSudahBisa = perkembanganAdapter.idYangSudahBisa();

                anakYangDipilih.getId();
                anakYangDipilih.setLevel1(idYangSudahBisa);
                anakYangDipilih.setCreatedBy(((Global) getApplicationContext()).getTherapist().getId());
                anakYangDipilih.setUpdatedBy(((Global) getApplicationContext()).getTherapist().getId());
                anakYangDipilih.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                anakYangDipilih.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
                anakYangDipilih = childDao.saveChild(anakYangDipilih);

                Toast.makeText(PerkembanganLevel1.this, "Perkembangan Anak pada level 1 Berhasil Diperbarui", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

this is the **adapter**

```
public class PerkembanganAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContentHistory> {


    String idYangSudahBisa;

    private ChildDao childDao;
    private Child anakYangDipilih;

    public ArrayList<ContentHistory> contentHistories;

    public PerkembanganAdapter(Context context, int id, ArrayList<ContentHistory> contentHistories){
        super(context, id, contentHistories);
        this.contentHistories = new ArrayList<>();
        this.contentHistories.addAll(contentHistories);



        childDao = new ChildDao(getContext());
        childDao.open();

        anakYangDipilih = ((Global) context.getApplicationContext()).getChild();
        this.idYangSudahBisa = anakYangDipilih.getLevel1();

    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        CheckBox checkBoxes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_perkembangan, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVListPerkembangan);
            viewHolder.checkBoxes = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CBListPerkembangan);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            viewHolder.checkBoxes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
                    ContentHistory contentHistory = (ContentHistory) checkBox.getTag();
                    contentHistory.setSelected(checkBox.isChecked());
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                        idYangSudahBisa = idYangSudahBisa + ","+contentHistory.getId();
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+idYangSudahBisa,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        idYangSudahBisa = idYangSudahBisa.replace(","+contentHistory.getId(), "");
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+idYangSudahBisa,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });



        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        ContentHistory contentHistory = contentHistories.get(position);
        viewHolder.title.setText(contentHistory.getTitle());

        viewHolder.checkBoxes.setChecked(contentHistory.getSelected());
        viewHolder.checkBoxes.setTag(contentHistory);


        return convertView;

    }

    public String idYangSudahBisa(){

        return this.idYangSudahBisa;
    }

}
...
```

Comment: Firstly you need to check whether your data is correctly updated.You can check your database by [Android Debug DataBase](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a submit button as you can update (toggele) the database in real time when the checkbox is clicked.

The important aspect is the addition of a method in ContentDao such as :-

```
public void toggleCheckedById(long id) {

    db.execSQL(
            "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " SET " + COLUMN_CHECKED + " = NOT  " + COLUMN_CHECKED +
                    " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}
    );
}
```

- This equates to `UPDATE the_table SET the_check_column = NOT the_check_column WHERE the_id_column =?`

  - noting that ? is replaced (bound) using the 2nd paarmeter passed to execSQL which in this case is a String[] containing a single element which is the **id** of the row to be changed.

This can be called from the CheckBox's onClick passing the id extracted from the view's Tag.

Consider this cutdown version of your code :-

The database helper (perhaps your **Global.java** class) **DatabaseHelper.java** :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "perkembangan.db";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createContentSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + ContentDao.TABLE_NAME +
        "(" +
                ContentDao.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                ContentDao.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                ContentDao.COLUMN_CHECKED + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(createContentSQL);
        /* ADD SOME TESTING DATA WHEN THE DATABASE IS CREATED */
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            cv.clear();
            cv.put(ContentDao.COLUMN_NAME,"Name" + String.valueOf(i));
            db.insert(ContentDao.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public static String qualifyColumnName(String table, String column) {
        return table + "." + column;
    }
}
```

- Note that this adds 3 rows for testing.
- You probably don't need this.

**ContentDao.java** (an interpretation thereof) :-

```
public class ContentDao {

    private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "content";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String QUALIFIEDCOLUMN_ID = DatabaseHelper.qualifyColumnName(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_ID);
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHECKED = "checked";



    public ContentDao(Context context) {
        db =(sInstance = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)).getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void toggleCheckedById(long id) {

        db.execSQL(
                "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " SET " + COLUMN_CHECKED + " = NOT  " + COLUMN_CHECKED +
                        " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}
        );
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return db;
    }

    public int updateCheckedById(ContentHistory ch) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHECKED,ch.isChecked());
        return db.update(TABLE_NAME,cv,COLUMN_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(ch.getId())});
    }

    public ArrayList<ContentHistory> getContentHistory() {
        ArrayList<ContentHistory> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rv.add(new ContentHistory(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)),
                    csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)),
                    csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CHECKED))> 0)
            );
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }



    public class ContentHistory {
        private long id;
        private String name;
        private boolean checked;

        ContentHistory(long id, String name, boolean checked) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** for convenience the ContentHistory class has been included
- name has been used instead of Title (didn't realise until later)
- As said the important addition is the **toggleCheckedById** method.

**PerkembanganAdapter.java**

```
public class PerkembanganAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContentDao.ContentHistory> {

    ContentDao contentDao;


    public ArrayList<ContentDao.ContentHistory> contentHistories;

    public PerkembanganAdapter(Context context, int id, ArrayList<ContentDao.ContentHistory> contentHistories){
        super(context, id, contentHistories);
        contentDao = new ContentDao(context);
        this.contentHistories = new ArrayList<>();
        this.contentHistories.addAll(contentHistories);
        /*
        childDao = new ChildDao(getContext());
        childDao.open();

        anakYangDipilih = ((Global) context.getApplicationContext()).getChild();
        this.idYangSudahBisa = anakYangDipilih.getLevel1();

        */

    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        CheckBox checkBoxes;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_perkembangan, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.TVListPerkembangan);
            viewHolder.checkBoxes = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CBListPerkembangan);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            viewHolder.checkBoxes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) v;
                    ContentDao.ContentHistory contentHistory = (ContentDao.ContentHistory) checkBox.getTag();
                    contentHistory.setChecked(checkBox.isChecked());
                    contentDao.toggleCheckedById(contentHistory.getId()); //<<<<< will update (toggle) database in real time
                    /* NOT NEEDED
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                        //idYangSudahBisa = idYangSudahBisa + ","+contentHistory.getId();
                        //Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), ""+idYangSudahBisa,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //idYangSudahBisa = idYangSudahBisa.replace(","+contentHistory.getId(), "");
                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+idYangSudahBisa,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     */
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ContentDao.ContentHistory contentHistory = contentHistories.get(position);
        viewHolder.title.setText(contentHistory.getName());
        viewHolder.checkBoxes.setChecked(contentHistory.isChecked());
        viewHolder.checkBoxes.setTag(contentHistory);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

- Note much of the original code has been commeneted out and just the important code needed to demonstrate has been left in.
- Names that appear to be foreign language names have also been omitted/changed for convenience.
- **Obviously the code will have to be adapted to suit.** It is the technique that is being demonstrated.

**PerkembanganLevel1.java** the Activity :-

```
public class PerkembanganLevel1 extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ContentDao contentDao;
    private ListView level1;
    private PerkembanganAdapter perkembanganAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ContentDao.ContentHistory> contentHistory;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perkembangan_level1);
        level1 = this.findViewById(R.id.level1);

        contentDao = new ContentDao(this);
        manageListView();

        /*contentDao.open();

        childDao = new ChildDao(this);
        childDao.open();

        anakYangDipilih = ((Global) getApplicationContext()).getChild();

        idYangSudahBisa = anakYangDipilih.getLevel1();

         */

        /*
        ArrayList<ContentDao.ContentHistory> listKataLevel1 = (ArrayList<ContentDao.ContentHistory>) contentDao.getAllWordByLevel(1);

        perkembanganAdapter = new PerkembanganAdapter(this, R.layout.list_perkembangan, listKataLevel1);

        //ListView level1 =  findViewById(R.id.LVPlv1);
        level1.setAdapter(perkembanganAdapter);
        Log.i("listKataLevel1 ", String.valueOf(listKataLevel1));
        level1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                contentHistory = (ContentDao.ContentHistory) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.BtnPLv1Submit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                idYangSudahBisa = perkembanganAdapter.idYangSudahBisa();

                anakYangDipilih.getId();
                anakYangDipilih.setLevel1(idYangSudahBisa);
                anakYangDipilih.setCreatedBy(((Global) getApplicationContext()).getTherapist().getId());
                anakYangDipilih.setUpdatedBy(((Global) getApplicationContext()).getTherapist().getId());
                anakYangDipilih.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                anakYangDipilih.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
                anakYangDipilih = childDao.saveChild(anakYangDipilih);

                Toast.makeText(PerkembanganLevel1.this, "Perkembangan Anak pada level 1 Berhasil Diperbarui", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

         */

    }

    /* Will refresh the Listview when returning from an invoked activity just in case data has changed */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView();
    }

    private void manageListView() {
        contentHistory = contentDao.getContentHistory();
        if (perkembanganAdapter == null) {
            perkembanganAdapter = new PerkembanganAdapter(this,R.layout.list_perkembangan,contentHistory);
            level1.setAdapter(perkembanganAdapter);

        } else {
            perkembanganAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Not really needed if updating when checked
        }
    }
}
```

## Demo results

### When first run :-

[image]

### Second Run row 2 ticked and then restarted

[image]

### Third Run all 3 checkeck boxes reversed and then restarted

[image]